# Drag fill formula with alternate cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a formula which goes `=UPPER(Raw!B10)` and I want to drag fill this formula down a column however as the fill goes down the cell reference needs to be increased by 2 rather then 1.

Eg. `=UPPER(Raw!B12), =UPPER(Raw!B14), =UPPER(Raw!B16)`

Is there a way to do this without any complex formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX with some math:

```
=UPPER(INDEX(Raw!B:B,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+12))
```

Put this in the first cell and drag down.

The `*2` denotes the pattern

The `+12` is the starting row.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do what you want is a bit of a workaround, but can be useful if you have to use this on a lot of cells.

On a separate worksheet start with the formula pattern and drag fill until you get to the upper number you need ex. =UPPER(Raw!B102). Next make another column next to it starting with 1, 2, 3 etc and drag fill to the end of you Raw! column. Lastly make a new column of alternating TRUE, FALSE, TRUE and drag fill (you need a minimum of 4 for drag fill to work correctly, ex. True, False, True, False).

Then sort by the third column (TRUE/FALSE), and delete whichever rows correspond to the odd Raw! Cells (ex =UPPER(Raw!B13) etc). Basically all evens should either all be TRUE/FALSE and the odds should all be the opposite.

Now that you've gotten rid of the unwanted ODD formulas re-sort by the second column to get them all in order (if they aren't already, this middle column was just a precaution).

Should be an easy copy paste after that to your original document.

Comment: Scott Craner's Solution was much more tech savvy than mine :)